# Was the S-83 Personal CP/M CPU used in commercial computers?

Tags: z80, cpu, cp-m

The [June 1984 edition of Practical Computing](https://worldradiohistory.com/UK/Practical-Computing/80s/Practical-Computing-1984-06-S-OCR.pdf) magazine (page 43) refers to the American Microsystems Incorporated S-83 CPU as a Z80 compatible CPU with an 8K mask ROM capable of holding Digital Research's [Personal CP/M](https://www.retrotechnology.com/dri/personalcpm.html). This feature, coupled with better dynamic RAM handling than the Z80 along with a non-multiplexed 16-bit address bus, could have resulted in very low chip count Z80 computers.

Apart from this one article, there's not much else out there about the S-83. Did it get used in real hardware, or was it (as I suspect) another puff of mid-80's vapour that never made it beyond a press release?

Comment: As an aside, enhanced chips were quite common, at least in the embedded world. I worked on Dallas Semiconductor CPUs that were basically Motorola 68000-family chips with extra stuff added to the top of the chip (like RTC or extra I/O). Why buy (and design for) N chips when you can get away with one? :-)

Comment: Also in https://books.google.com/books?id=fi4EAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA23&lpg=PA23&dq=s-83+cpu+%22ami%22+cp/m&source=bl&ots=CPxH9-zLop&sig=ACfU3U3znr64-le8PhCjYRAhaf1-AVG56w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjy44ONqqD9AhXcElkFHXhNDDsQ6AF6BAglEAI#v=onepage&q=s-83%20cpu%20%22ami%22%20cp%2Fm&f=false in InfoWorld

Comment: The Z80 already has a non-multiplexed 16-bit address bus.

Comment: The 1985 AMI MOS Products handbook has a "Preliminary Data Sheet" for the S83, with 31 pages laying it all out. However, the next data books I have found (1990 at bitsavers) have no mention of it. Perhaps vaporware, but they got pretty far down the road first.

Comment: @paxdiablo early SOCs?

Answer (score -2):

While I know about Personal CP/M, that S83 is new to me.

I would not expect Z80 nor CP/M to show up in personal computers (or any general available machines showing computer like features) as late as 1984, or since this was an announcement, even later. Also, wasn't 'persona# CP/M DR's offering for embedded systems? So the use case may be much like with DOS after ca. 1990 - embedded systems, which are always build from comparably simpel and more mature components. We did use Z80 for *new* designs way into the 2000s.

Comment: It didn't seem to stop Amstrad with their CPC and PCW machines: all released after 1984, and all (except the first CPC 464) supplied with CP/M

Comment: Also the Commodore 128 in 1985, though let's face it ‒ neither was bought for its CP/M compatibility.  Later, in the 90s, TI based its first family of graphing calculators on the Z80.

Comment: KayPro was releasing new Z-80 systems in 1984.

Comment: Nice list of systems, but they were all continuation of existing systems to feature an existing base, not a new design - and all of them on the way out.

Comment: The Z80 also showed up (without CP/M) in portable word processors like the NC100 as late as 1993. These included BASIC, which I would count as 'showing computer like features'.

Comment: Saying a Z80 was obsolete as a general personal computing CPU because there was the 80286 and 68000  is like saying a Core i5 is obsolete today because there are Threadrippers and comparable HEDT CPUs. An 80286 PC was COSTLY in 1985.